# Why buttons without icons in Material Design

Tags: icon, button, google-material-design

In Google's Material Design, do the guidelines prefer buttons without icons next to text? On http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html no such examples can be found. Is it written somewhere why?

(I know the floating action button or paper icon button have icons; I'm talking about text buttons.)

Comment: Are you asking why there aren't buttons with *both* icon *and* text together? If so, I assume they consider it redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the developer pages (http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html):

> Both an icon and text is most appropriate when they complement each other: each carrying its own bit of information, but together making a larger whole.

This may be the contributing factor in the design guide where no such example is present

Comment: Updating, the quoted excerpt is not part of the material design guidelines anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I might be late to this. But in Material Design website it does have a [sample](https://material.io/components/buttons/#contained-button) of it.

In most cases I think text only or icon only are sufficient to describe what it does. I came across a scenario where the button text describes the item that user is selecting and button icon describes what happens when the button is clicked. It seems more 'instructive' to me. But I may be wrong.

The following examples are from Material Design website.

[image]

> Do.
>   Use icons that clearly communicate their meaning.

[image]

> Don’t.
>   Don’t vertically align an icon and text in the center of a contained button.

[image]

> Don’t.
>   Don’t use two icons in the same button.

Comment: Hi Ryan, welcome to GDSE! Thanks for your answer. We like longer answers here, that explain the _why_ as well as the _how_. You might want to [edit] your answer to add more information and increase the quality. Feel free to browse the site, leave more answers, ask a question of your own and upvote quality content.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out. :)